# Targeting SVG with CSS

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

Is there a way for me to target SVG with CSS? They appear like broken images in IE8 downwards and I'd like to hide them using modernizr e.g. I was hoping for something like...

```
.no-svg object[type=svg] {
  display:none;
}
```

I'm using this to embed SVG into my page as recommended in http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" 
  width="100" height="100" style="float:right" 
  data="http://blog.codedread.com/clipart/apple.svgz">
<span/></object>
```

Comment: Put the svg into a wrapper and hide that perhaps? - since on IE prior to 9 svg is not supported as you note.

Comment: Hi Mark, I was hoping for an easy way of doing this using CSS selectors, without stuffing the mark-up. wrapping a div around it and adding a class is a last resort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` attribute in your markup is `image/svg+xml`. Your attribute selector `object[type=svg]` looks for a `type` attribute which is *exactly* `svg`, so your object won't match.

You should specify the full MIME type as in your markup (you need the quotes here, or it won't work; see [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) for details):

```
.no-svg object[type="image/svg+xml"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Or if you'd like you can use a substring attribute selector, but I prefer the above:

```
.no-svg object[type*=svg] {
  display:none;
}
```